Just got a new laptop with Ubuntu from Compudopt and it doesnt let me install anything including new software
So I just got a computer from a Compudopt giveaway and it runs on Ubuntu Linux but I cant do anything on it besides going on the Internet. Ive tried to do software updates but it gives me errors.
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Reading package lists... Done               

Any advice on what to do? Should I take it to a technician to have it looked at and install windows 11? I do have have an internet connection using Wifi, I am able to use google like normal.
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 34:48:ed:42:91:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s31f6
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether f8:e4:e3:32:1f:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname wlp0s20f3
inet 10.0.0.153/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
   valid_lft 172748sec preferred_lft 172748sec
inet6 2601:2c3:c681:a850::64b2/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 345550sec preferred_lft 345550sec
inet6 2601:2c3:c681:a850:d70b:79f2:afb1:310/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
   valid_lft 283sec preferred_lft 283sec
inet6 2601:2c3:c681:a850:bc52:9ea6:becf:f3b6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 283sec preferred_lft 283sec
inet6 fe80::acfb:aa2f:27c6:8ddf/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/compudopt/compudopt-testing/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.2.2:8000 (192.168.2.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.2.2:8000:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Are you connected to the internet when you run these commands? Are you behind a VPN?

Yes I am because I am able to use the internet on the laptop perfectly fine.

How is the computer connected to the Internet? Cable, Wi-Fi, mobile phone? Add these information to your question. The more detail you can provide the better.

It is connected through wifi .

Do you know what device this IP address 192.168.2.2 belongs to?

uhhh no i dont know, my best guess would be my other computer or phone.

Yes, you should install windows 11.

@Organic Marble Would it be better for me to take it to a technician?

Please post the output of the command sudo apt update.

You are free to install Windows 11 on the computer if you don't want to use Ubuntu. We can try to help you fix the Ubuntu problem. In case you want to install Windows 11, it is upto your expertise whether you can do it on your own or whether you need the help of a technician.

I know nothing about Ubuntu so id be better off to take it to a technician.

The last code is the sudo apt update

Try this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/124466. After that, try running sudo apt update again and see if there are still any errors.

I had the same errors.

Are you connecting the computer to the Internet using your phone? Can you try another method such as going to an Internet cafe, Starbucks, etc. and use the cafe's WiFi? It looks like a problem with Internet connection. Phone's internet may work for web surfing but may may not work for complex operations.
